# Detect :active link with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to style an `a:active` link using Javascript (because the CSS is editable by a person and stored in a file, so I can't just put the styling in a CSS file).

Is there any way in JS to check whether a particular link is `:active` or not? (not using jQuery)

Comment: as long as your stylesheet is loaded after the user editible stylesheet you can override it with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `mousedown` and a `mouseup` handler to every link. Mark it as active when the mousedown event fires and unactive when the mouseup event fires.

Comment: Well... doesn't cover 100% of the cases, but I guess it will have to do. (Doesn't work if you click the button, hold the mouse bttn down, and release it somewhere else, not over the button)